# natas11 helper program

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

### Intro

I've been having fun with `natas` a wargame, from [overthewire](http://overthewire.org/wargames/natas/).

To pass a [certain stage](http://natas11.natas.labs.overthewire.org/) I had to do some xor'ing, in combination with base64 encoding/decoding. So I wrote a little python utility to help me pass that stage.

Any feedback on the code I've written is helpfull, but I'm especially interested in the `repeated_substring()` function. I don't think my function is the most optimised way of handling that.

When I run the code it should output the newly generated cookie value:

`b'ClVLIh4ASCsCBE8lAxMacFMOXTlTWxooFhRXJh4FGnBTVF4sFxFeLFMK'`

---

### Code

```
import base64

def xor_break_cookie(cookie):
    """Breaking the key"""
    json = b'{"showpassword":"no","bgcolor":"#ffffff"}'
    return ''.join([chr(cookie[i] ^ json[i % len(json)]) for i in range(len(cookie))])

def decode_base64(data):
    """Decoding with the missing padding"""
    missing = len(data) % 4
    if missing != 0:
        data += b'=' * (4 - missing)
    return base64.decodestring(data)

def xor_gen_cookie(key):
    """Getting the new cookie value"""
    json = b'{"showpassword":"yes","bgcolor":"#ffffff"}'
    return ''.join([chr(json[i] ^ key[i % len(key)]) for i in range(len(json))])

def repeated_substring(text):
    """Gets the longest repeated xor key from text"""
    length = x = y = m = 0
    for y in range(len(text)):       
        for x in range(len(text)):     
            substring = text[y:x]
            if len(substring) > length and text.count(substring) >= m and len(substring) > 1:
                m, length, match = text.count(substring), len(substring), substring
    return match

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cookie = decode_base64(b'ClVLIh4ASCsCBE8lAxMacFMZV2hdVVotEhhUJQNVAmhSEV4sFxFeaAw')
    password = repeated_substring(xor_break_cookie(cookie))
    new_cookie = xor_gen_cookie(bytes(str.encode(password)))
    print(base64.encodestring(bytes(str.encode(new_cookie))).rstrip())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `xor_break_cookie` is almost exactly the same as `xor_gen_cookie`. I'd change them to be the same function, `xor_repeat`, with varing input.
- Rather than using `a[i] ^ b[i % len(...)] for i in range(len(...))`, you can use zip, and [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

  ```
  v ^ r for v, r in zip(value, cycle(repeater))
  ```
- Rather than using `str.encode('abc')`, you can use `'abc'.encode()`. It also doesn't make sense to use `str.encode`, it's un-common to see in Python, and provides no benifit here.
- Rather than using `bytes('abc'.encode())` you can just use `'abc'.encode()`.
- Rather than `''.join(...).encode()`, you can use `bytes(...)`.
- In `decode_base64`, if you merge the modifications of missing into one line you get:

  ```
  missing = 4 - (len(data) % 4) if (len(data) % 4) != 0 else 0
  ```

  This can be simplified if you use two modulos, rather than an if. \$(4 - i \% 4) \% 4\$.
  This however can be further simplified, if you make the left hand side negative, and so you can use \$-i \% 4\$.

  And so I'd use:

  ```
  def decode_base64(data):
      return base64.decodestring(data + b'=' * (-len(data) % 4))
  ```
- You can ensure that `len(substring) > 1`, if you start `x` at `y+1`.
- It doesn't make sense to me to generate values, and also find the max in the same function. Split them apart.
- By splitting the generating code, and the max finding code apart, you can use `max`:

  ```
  max(_repeated_substring(text), key=lambda t: (len(t), text.count(t)))
  ```
- Rather than having \$O(n^3)\$ time complexity, you can get a \$O(n^2)\$ time and \$O(n)\$ space complexity solution by using `Counter`.

In all I'd use something like the following. I also provide the above two ways to find the maximum:

```
import base64
from itertools import cycle
from collections import Counter

def xor_repeat(value, repeater):
    return bytes(v ^ r for v, r in zip(value, cycle(repeater)))

def decode_base64(data):
    return base64.decodestring(data + b'=' * (-len(data) % 4))

def _repeated_substring(text):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(text)):
            yield text[i:j]

def repeated_substring(text):
    return max(_repeated_substring(text), key=lambda t: (len(t), text.count(t)))

def repeated_substring(text):
    vals = Counter(_repeated_substring(text))
    return max(vals.items(), key=lambda i: (len(i[0]), i[1]))[0]

BREAK_JSON = b'{"showpassword":"no","bgcolor":"#ffffff"}'
GEN_JSON = b'{"showpassword":"yes","bgcolor":"#ffffff"}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cookie = decode_base64(b'ClVLIh4ASCsCBE8lAxMacFMZV2hdVVotEhhUJQNVAmhSEV4sFxFeaAw')
    password = repeated_substring(xor_repeat(cookie, BREAK_JSON))
    new_cookie = xor_repeat(GEN_JSON, password)
    print(base64.encodestring(new_cookie).rstrip())
```